# How to get rid of side menu button borders

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2

So I have a ionic mobile application and I'm currently improving the user interface design of the side menu.

[image]

So the problem here is that I having a hard time removing the border of each button.

Here's my code:

```
   <ion-content>
<ion-list no-border>
  <button menuClose ion-item class="profileContainer color" text-center (click)="openProfile()">
    <img src="{{profileImage}}" style="height: 20%; width: 30%;">
    <h1>{{profileName}}</h1><p>{{profileEmail}}</p>
  </button>
  <button class="otin" menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
    {{p.title}}
  </button>
  <button class="otin" menuClose ion-item (click)="logoutUser(event)">
    Logout
  </button>
</ion-list>
```

SASS

```
  .profileContainer{
// padding-bottom: 1rem;
// margin: 0 auto;
padding-left: 0;
}
  .otin{
 background-color: map-get($colors, headerbackground);
 }
```

How do I get rid of the white border above and below the buttons? I tried `border-style:none`, but I'm still facing the same issues.

Answer (score 1):

Add below code on your SASS file, hope it will remove the border bottom.

```
  .otin.item-block .item-inner, .item-md.item-block .item-inner {
    border: 0 !important;
}
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: hello i added the code you mentioned but still gives me borders. pictures is updated at top

Comment: Each items is loading with different class. I updated code. That code should work. Let me know if it works

Comment: hi again. still facing the same issue :((